# Getting avg_delay by destination

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have here a dataframe (flights_delay): 
[image]

In this dataframe (flights_delay), i have duplicate destinations (in the "dest" column). I am trying to get the average delay ("avg_delay" column) by destination ("dest" column). I have tried this code:

```
sum_avg_delay <- aggregate(avg_delay~dest,flights_delay,sum)$avg_delay
```

Unfortunately, I get a vector of numbers without any destination labels.

I've also tried the `dplyr::summarise` function, but this returns an error.

There must be a simpler way to get the average delay by destination.

Comment: Probably `aggregate(avg_delay ~ dest,flights_delay, sum)` for a 2 column data.frame or `with(flights_delay, tapply(avg_delay, dest, sum)` for a named vector.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, just simplify:

```
df <- data.frame(dest=c("IAH","IAH","MIA","BQN","ATL","ATL"),
             avg_delay=c(13,24,35,-19,-31,8))

aggregate(avg_delay ~ dest, sum, data=df)

  dest avg_delay
1  ATL       -23
2  BQN       -19
3  IAH        37
4  MIA        35
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr`:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

df <- data.frame(dest=c("IAH","IAH","MIA","BQN","ATL","ATL"),
                 avg_delay=c(13,24,35,-19,-31,8))

# average delay by destination
df %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>% 
  summarise(avg_delay = mean(avg_delay))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>     dest avg_delay
#>   <fctr>     <dbl>
#> 1    ATL     -11.5
#> 2    BQN     -19.0
#> 3    IAH      18.5
#> 4    MIA      35.0

# sum of average delay by destination
df %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>% 
  summarise(avg_delay = sum(avg_delay))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>     dest avg_delay
#>   <fctr>     <dbl>
#> 1    ATL       -23
#> 2    BQN       -19
#> 3    IAH        37
#> 4    MIA        35
```